# Unable to load dataset using IBM DB2 LOAD tool

Tags: sql, db2, load

Error for batch element #1: "WQX79824" does not have the privilege to perform operation "IMPLICIT CREATE SCHEMA".. SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=4.26.14
Number of occurrences: 1

Comment: Depending on what the LOAD command does, you need to have the right privileges. Without more context, there is no help

Comment: It's not a Db2 `load` utility problem. `load` does not create any tables itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming issue, instead it is a configuration issue.

Either ask your DBA to grant the relevant authority and permissions to the authID you use (WQX79824) to connect to the database, or alternately connect to the database with a **different** authID which already has the required permissions and authorities to create objects and do loads etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have sent DBA a mail since and they are yet to reply me with a solution to the privilege issue. I don't have password to the other authID that has permissions to create. So my understanding is that I can use any other schemas to LOAD a CSV as data set? But I do not see any of the other Schemas when I use the LOAD tool